# C# how to get info from one form that is saved to a txt file to show on another form

Tags: c#

Okay, sorry this is my first time posting but, here we go. I am writing a program that has one form that shows info that is stored in a .txt file. There is a new button that allows me to put the new info to that file using another form. When I save the info, it stores it in the file, but When it goes back to the original form, the info doesn't display. Below is all the code I have put in. Yes, I am new to C#.

First Form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<String> pateintNumber;
    public List<String> patientFirstName;
    public List<String> patientMiddleName;
    public List<String> patientLastName;
    public List<String> patientDOB;
    public bool test = false;
    public int counter;
    public int g;

    public void cacheInfo()
    {
        StreamReader getLength = new StreamReader("../../../patient info.txt");
        string lineInfo = getLength.ReadLine();

        counter = 0;
        while (lineInfo != null)
        {
            counter++;
            lineInfo = getLength.ReadLine();
        }
        getLength.Close();
        //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(counter));
        pateintNumber = new List<String>(1);
        patientFirstName = new List<String>(1);
        patientMiddleName = new List<String>(1);
        patientLastName = new List<String>(1);
        patientDOB = new List<String>(1);


        g = 0;
        StreamReader getInfo = new StreamReader("../../../patient info.txt");
        lineInfo = getInfo.ReadLine();
        while (g < counter)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(lineInfo);
            String[] info = lineInfo.Split(',');
            pateintNumber.Add(info[0]);
            patientFirstName.Add(info[1]);
            patientMiddleName.Add(info[2]);
            patientLastName.Add(info[3]);
            patientDOB.Add(info[4]);
            lineInfo = getInfo.ReadLine();
            g++;
        }

        g = 0;
        lbPateintNumber.Text = pateintNumber[g];
        lbPateintFIrstName.Text = patientFirstName[g];
        lbPateintMiddleName.Text = patientMiddleName[g];
        lbPateintLastName.Text = patientLastName[g];
        lbPateintDOB.Text = patientDOB[g];

        getInfo.Close();
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cacheInfo();
    }

    private void Form_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g++;

        if (g > counter - 1)
        {
            g = 0;
            lbPateintNumber.Text = pateintNumber[g];
            lbPateintFIrstName.Text = patientFirstName[g];
            lbPateintMiddleName.Text = patientMiddleName[g];
            lbPateintLastName.Text = patientLastName[g];
            lbPateintDOB.Text = patientDOB[g];
        }
        else 
        {
            lbPateintNumber.Text = pateintNumber[g];
            lbPateintFIrstName.Text = patientFirstName[g];
            lbPateintMiddleName.Text = patientMiddleName[g];
            lbPateintLastName.Text = patientLastName[g];
            lbPateintDOB.Text = patientDOB[g];
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g--;

        if (g < 0)
        {
            g = counter - 1;
            lbPateintNumber.Text = pateintNumber[g];
            lbPateintFIrstName.Text = patientFirstName[g];
            lbPateintMiddleName.Text = patientMiddleName[g];
            lbPateintLastName.Text = patientLastName[g];
            lbPateintDOB.Text = patientDOB[g];
        }
        else
        {
            lbPateintNumber.Text = pateintNumber[g];
            lbPateintFIrstName.Text = patientFirstName[g];
            lbPateintMiddleName.Text = patientMiddleName[g];
            lbPateintLastName.Text = patientLastName[g];
            lbPateintDOB.Text = patientDOB[g];
        }
    }

    private void barNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }

}//end of program
```

Second Form

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string newFirstName;
    public string newMiddleName;
    public string newLastName;
    public string newDOB;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        StreamReader getLength = new StreamReader("../../../patient info.txt");
        string lineInfo = getLength.ReadLine();

        while (lineInfo != null)
        {
            counter++;
            lineInfo = getLength.ReadLine();
        }
        getLength.Close();
        counter++;
        StreamWriter writeNewPatient = new StreamWriter("../../../patient info.txt", true );
        writeNewPatient.WriteLine("000" + counter + ", " + tbFirstName.Text + ", " + tbMiddleName.Text + ", " + tbLastName.Text + ", " + tbDOB.Text);
        writeNewPatient.Flush();
        writeNewPatient.Close();
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.pateintNumber.Add("000" + counter);
        frm.patientFirstName.Add(tbFirstName.Text);
        frm.patientMiddleName.Add(tbMiddleName.Text);
        frm.patientLastName.Add(tbLastName.Text);
        frm.patientDOB.Add(tbDOB.Text);
        frm.counter = frm.counter++;

        this.Close(); //to turn off current app
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
} //end of program
```

Comment: You're got way too much detail in here.  You could probably cut this down a lot and still have something that shows the issue.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your second form like

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string newFirstName;
    public string newMiddleName;
    public string newLastName;
    public string newDOB;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form1 m_MainForm;
    public Form2(Form1 form)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_MainForm = form;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        StreamReader getLength = new StreamReader("../../../patient info.txt");
        string lineInfo = getLength.ReadLine();

        while (lineInfo != null)
        {
            counter++;
            lineInfo = getLength.ReadLine();
        }
        getLength.Close();
        counter++;
        StreamWriter writeNewPatient = new StreamWriter("../../../patient info.txt", true );
        writeNewPatient.WriteLine("000" + counter + ", " + tbFirstName.Text + ", " + tbMiddleName.Text + ", " + tbLastName.Text + ", " + tbDOB.Text);
        writeNewPatient.Flush();
        writeNewPatient.Close();
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.pateintNumber.Add("000" + counter);
        frm.patientFirstName.Add(tbFirstName.Text);
        frm.patientMiddleName.Add(tbMiddleName.Text);
        frm.patientLastName.Add(tbLastName.Text);
        frm.patientDOB.Add(tbDOB.Text);
        frm.counter = frm.counter++;

        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, m_MainForm))
        {
            m_MainForm.cacheInfo(); 
        }
        this.Close(); //to turn off current app
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, m_MainForm))
        {
           m_MainForm.cacheInfo(); 
        }
        this.Close();
    }
} //end of program
```

and call second form from first one like this

```
private void barNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks work like a charm. I can now walk through it and find out where I went wrong.